# Incrementar valores después de un INSERT

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Tengo una consulta, estoy realizando un programa de gestión de ordenes de servicio, en el FORM cuenta con los datos del cliente, y tengo dos campos los cuales se encargan de mantener el numero del documento y otro campo que cuenta con el id de la llamada, y quisiera conocer si es posible obtener un Query que en el momento de Guardar los datos en la tabla utilizando el INSERT quisiera que esos dos campos (id de la llamada y el numero del documento) sea aumentados + 1 automáticamente.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! con un trigger? realmente no se entiende que estas buscando

Answer (score 1):

lo que puedes hacer es que en el identity de tu tabla el incremental sea en base a 2 en vez de en base 1

ejemplo:

```
Create table TablaNombre (

[KEyTable] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,2)


)
```